# Delphi XE5 Firemonkey TTabItem and TEdit repaint coordination

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, repaint

I created a TTabControl with two TTabItems.  On each TTabItem there is one (or more) TImageViewers and several TEdits.  When I click on the TImageViewer, a modal screen pops up, I set some values, and I want to report those values to the user through the TEdits.  So on returning from the Modal screen,
I execute

```
editn.text := whateveritis;
```

I then say

```
editn.repaint;
```

Nothing happens.  I say TTabItem.repaint.  Nothing happens.  I click the other TTabIem and then come back to the first TabItem and, voila, the Edit control contains the right information.  So my editn.text := whateveritis must be working (that's the only write to the TEdit), but I can't get the blinkin' control to show the result without going off-tab.  How do I get it to redisplay as soon as I change the content?  Do I need to write an OnChange routine that is one line, self.repaint?  Seems ugly, and I'd hope there's a more global approach.  Suggestions?

In light of initial comments, let me give more details.  Setup: In main screen, drop in tabcontrol, and in tabcontrol drop in 2 tabitems.  In tabitem1, drop in a timageviewer and 4 tedits (plus other stuff, probably irrelevant).  Image gets dropped into the imageviewer (and displays correctly).  The onclick event activates the following (ellipsis cuts out irrelevant code):

```
procedure TSCKMain.ImageViewer1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  lochold, scrollhold : tpoint;
  backfromwavform : tmodalresult;

begin
  lochold.X := mouseloccallback.x;
  lochold.Y := mouseloccallback.y;
  scrollhold.X := round(imageviewer1.ViewportPosition.X);
  scrollhold.Y := round(imageviewer1.ViewportPosition.Y);
  …
  repeat backfromwavform := Wavform.Showmodal until backfromwavform<>mrnone;
  case backfromwavform of
  mrOK : begin   {blue end}
    Specsingle.BlueEnd.X := lochold.X;
    Specsingle.BlueEnd.y := lochold.y;
    edit13.Text := inttostr(Specsingle.BlueEnd.X);
    Edit14.Text := inttostr(Specsingle.BlueEnd.y);
    PublicWindowFlag := 'RePlot';
  end;
  mrContinue : begin {red end}
    Specsingle.RedEnd.X := lochold.X;
    Specsingle.RedEnd.y := lochold.y;
    edit15.Text := inttostr(Specsingle.RedEnd.X);
    Edit16.Text := inttostr(Specsingle.RedEnd.y);
    PublicWindowFlag := 'RePlot';
  end;
  …
  end;
  if PublicWindowFlag<>'Cancel' then
    if PublicWindowFlag='RePlot' then
      begin
        specsingle.RegenImage;
      end
    else
      showmessage('Single image semaphore error.  Debug.');
  Imageviewer1.scrollto(scrollhold.X-Imageviewer1.viewportposition.X, scrollhold.y-Imageviewer1.ViewportPosition.Y);
end;
```

The modal screen sends back either mrContinue or mrOK correctly, and the appropriate case executes.  However, edit13, edit14, edit15, and edit16 do not change their content.  However, if I click over to Tabitem2 and back to Tabitem1, they DO repaint and DO contain the correct characters, which they could only have gotten from the above code.  Conclusion: somehow, the edits aren’t repainting independently, but it’s not clear why.

Comment: If you set the text of a TEdit it's appearance will update with no need to repaint manually. We will need more information, especially the full code of the routine which calls the modal screen and sets the edit's text.

Answer (score -1):

Got it.  The canvas for the imageviewer, the canvas for the bitmap in the imageviewer, and the canvas for the parent form are all in play.  One must be sure that the canvas is the right one.  As soon as scenes got untangled between imageviewer.bitmap and everything else, the edits worked as one would expect.